# How to JOIN a table based on month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the number of appointments for each month.

The results are grouped into each month for a rolling-12-months graph.

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT a.time AS appointmentdatetime,
       m.text AS ref_month_text,
       m.month AS ref_month_int,
       YEAR(TIME) AS appointmentyear,
       COUNT(a.id) AS COUNT
FROM ref_months m LEFT JOIN
     appointment a
     ON m.month = MONTH(a.time) AND
        a.time >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 12 MONTH)
        AND a.dealershipid = '1' AND a.dealerstatus != 'No-Show'
GROUP BY m.month
ORDER BY appointmentyear ASC, m.month ASC
```

This is the result:

```
+----------------+--------------------+-------+--+
| ref_month_text | appointmentyear    | COUNT |  |
+----------------+--------------------+-------+--+
| February       |               2019 |    16 |  |
| March          |               2019 |    18 |  |
| April          |               2019 |    10 |  |
| May            |               2019 |    15 |  |
| June           |               2019 |    18 |  |
| July           |               2019 |    10 |  |
| August         |               2019 |    12 |  |
| September      |               2019 |    20 |  |
| October        |               2019 |     7 |  |
| November       |               2019 |    13 |  |
| December       |               2019 |     7 |  |
| January        |               2020 |    11 |  |
+----------------+--------------------+-------+--+
```

The grouping by month, on a rolling-12-months, and showing null when no data, is what I am getting, but the issue I am having is that the count is wrong for each month.

Eg. March 2019 should be 20.

I have tried all variations of JOIN types. But still returning wrong figures.

Comment: How do we know what the values should be?  Perhaps you should set up a db<>fiddle or something similar.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ngktSEcMRU8Gx3hLj2WaJH/0
As you mentioned in previous question, the error appears when executing in dbFiddle. Whereas on the live server it doesnt show this error.
ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP

Comment: . . The error is correct.  You should fix the query.

Comment: Would you be able to guide me in the right direction? Not sure how to remedy the issue

Comment: I am still getting the same error with your link?

Comment: . . https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mepDWQTVYgd1xfy88RZKkn/0.

Comment: That changes the results completely though...

Answer (score 2):

I simplified your query

```
SELECT
    YEAR(a.time) AS year,
    ANY_VALUE(MONTHNAME(a.time)) AS month,
    ANY_VALUE(COUNT(a.id)) AS counter,
    MONTH(a.time) AS mo
FROM
    appointment AS a 
GROUP BY
    year,mo
ORDER BY
    year ASC,
    mo ASC
```

Comment: Probably add a LIMIT 12; for MySQL

Comment: I get the following error with your solution:
Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.a.time' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ngktSEcMRU8Gx3hLj2WaJH/3

Comment: modified it for you, if you wanna have just 12 values, add limit 12

Comment: Thanks, but now: FUNCTION ANY_VALUE does not exist

Comment: `ANY_VALUE(COUNT(a.id)) AS counter,` must be `COUNT(a.id) AS counter,` (or better still `COUNT(*) AS counter,`).

Comment: Grouping by alias names is a MySQL extension by the way. I'd stick to the standard: `GROUP BY YEAR(a.time), MONTH(a.time)`. And if you even order by the expressions (`ORDER BY YEAR(a.time), MONTH(a.time)`), you don't even have to select `MONTH(a.time) AS mo`.

Comment: If you still get the error after changing `ANY_VALUE(COUNT(a.id))`to `COUNT(*)`, then you have a very old MySQL version and should update (though you could just use `MIN` or `MAX` instead of `ANY_VALUE` with your old version).